# How to parse single-quote char in PyMOL

Tags: pymol

I am writing parser to parse PyMOL files (language for bioinformatics).
I know that double-quote char makes a string like `"text"`. But single-quote char `'` is different. Here is example of PyMOL lines with this strange symbol.

```
load dat/names.pdb

select test,name O4'
select test,*/O4'

select test,*/O4'+O3'
select test,(*/O4',O3')
select test,name O4'+O3'
select test,name "O4'+O3'"

select test,name O4'+Na\+
select test,(name Na\+,O4')
select test,name Na\++O4'
select test,*/Na\++O4'

select test,*/O4'+O4

select test,*/O2\*+O2

select test,*/O2\*+O2'
```

To what language tokens does this quote apply? How to colorize such lines? Maybe quote-char is a word-char, or a separator char? In one example file I saw such usage of quote, it is string token `'text'`:

```
iterate (all),resn = 'NON'
```

This is valid code taked from [PyMOL GitHub repo](https://github.com/schrodinger/pymol-open-source/blob/master/test/inp/C0105names.pml).

Answer (score 0):

PyMOL is more a software than a language. It provides, however, a set of commands to support some python scripting. What your file contains is a set of such commands.

The first command `load dat/names.pdb` load a pdb file (a text file containing the 3D coordinates, names and other data about atoms from a molecule, usually - but not always - a protein). The full documentation about pdb files can be found [here](http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format).

The second and subsequent commands create a PyMOL selection (basically, a list of atoms) following a [specific syntax](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Selection_Algebra). The keyword `name` indicates that you want to select atoms whose name contains the string `O4'` (for the first `select` command). Note that the single quote is part of the atom name and NOT a language token. Usually, atom names with single quote characters points out atoms from nucleic acids (DNA or RNA).

The command `iterate (all),resn = 'NON'` is a PyMOL command to [iterate](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Iterate) over all atoms of a selection ; here, the selection is `(all)`, which means all the atoms loaded in the session. But the syntax doesn't seem correct to me. I assume that you want to iterate over all atoms that belongs to residues named `NON`, in which case your command should look like `iterate (resn NON), print name` to print the name of all atoms of the selection for instance. If you want to change the residues name of all atoms to `NON`, you should consider using the PyMOL command [`alter`](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php?title=Alter&redirect=no) instead.

Comment: This is valid code taken from https://github.com/schrodinger/pymol-open-source/blob/master/test/inp/C0105names.pml

Comment: I'm only stating that the `iterate` command you posted is not correct. The rest are valid PyMOL commands, with the single quote characters being part of the atom names.